# How to call two async functions one after the other?

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

I am a newbie in JavaScript and presently working with async/await in React Native. I have two async functions `getAsyncLocation` and `getParking`. `getAsyncLocation` gets location from device as well from route params (obtained when routed from another screen). `getParking` uses the state - `mapRegion` - assigned by `getAsyncLocation` to find relevant results.

However when I run them one after the other I am getting:-

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'mapRegion.latitude')]
```

I have following code:-

```
const [mapRegion, setmapRegion] = useState(null);

handleMapRegionChange = (mapRegion) => setmapRegion({ mapRegion });

  const handleCenterChange = (lat, lng) => setmapRegion({
    latitude: lat,
    longitude: lng,
    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
  })

async function getAsyncLocation() {
    if (route.params) { // obtained from some other screen
      handleCenterChange(route.params.lat, route.params.lng);
      console.log("route params for location ", mapRegion.latitude, mapRegion.longitude);
    }
    else {
      const { status, permissions } = await Permissions.askAsync(
        Permissions.LOCATION
      );

      if (status === "granted") {
        sethasLocationPermission(true);
        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
        setlocationResult(JSON.stringify(location));
        handleCenterChange(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);
      } else {
        alert("Location permission denied");
      }
    }
  }

  async function getParkings() {
    console.log("get parking runing")
    console.log("get parkig ", mapRegion.latitude, ", ", mapRegion.longitude);
    await axios.get(`http://${MyIp}:8080/booking/findParking`, {
      params: {
        lat: mapRegion.latitude,
        lng: mapRegion.longitude,
        rad: 10
      },
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
      }
    })
      .then((response) => {
        let parkingSpace = response.data;
        let parking = []
        for (let i = 0; i < parkingSpace.length; i++) {
          parking.push({
            spaceId: parkingSpace[i]._id,
            ownerId: parkingSpace[i].owner,
            location:
              { latitude: parkingSpace[i].latitude, longitude: parkingSpace[i].longitude }
          })
        }
        console.log(parking)
        setSpace(parking);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }

  async function getData() {
    await getAsyncLocation();
    await getParkings();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
```

I have tried to search it in various blogs and stackoverflow question but could not get a way around. Would appreciate any hint.

Comment: An async function can only wait for a promise, so in order to use the await keyword with await getAsyncLocation() and await getParkings() in getData(), make sure these functions do in fact return a promise. For example, return axios.get(...).

Comment: Agreed @RicardoAgra

Answer (score 0):

you can use another useEffect hook watching if the mapRegion state has been changed. (you can have as many useEffect hooks as you want in your app)

```
useEffect(() => {
    getAsyncLocation(); 
  }, []); // [] without any args, this will be called only once. We want to get device location only once

  useEffect(() => {
    getParkings();
  }, [mapRegion]) // since we have passed mapRegion as arg therefore it would be called whenever mapRegion is updated
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, in order to execute `getAsyncLocation` before `getParkings` you have to use Promise. But there is another problem: even if you run sequentially `getAsyncLocation` and `getParkings`, is not guaranteed that in `getParkings` `mapRegion` has the value setted by `getAsyncLocation` (because Hooks are async!). So how can solve your problem? You have several options. One is use 2 useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   getAsyncLocation(); 
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
   getParkings();
}, [mapRegion]);
```

This approach has 2 problems:

1. every time you load the component in which `useEffect`s live, first useEffect will be triggered (and maybe you don't want that).
2. every time `mapRegion` changes his value, second `useEffect` will be triggered (and maybe you don't want that).

So, I suggest a Promise approach as I said but passing value that `getParkings` needs as a result of `getAsyncLocation`. Your code becomes:

**getAsyncLocation**

```
async function getAsyncLocation() {
return new Promise(resolve => {
   let result = {lat: -1, lng: -1};
   if (route.params) { // obtained from some other screen
     handleCenterChange(route.params.lat, route.params.lng);
     console.log("route params for location ", mapRegion.latitude, mapRegion.longitude);
     result.lat = route.params.lat;
     result.lng = route.params.lng;
     resolve(result);
     return;
   }
   else {
     const { status, permissions } = await Permissions.askAsync(
       Permissions.LOCATION
    );

     if (status === "granted") {
       sethasLocationPermission(true);
       let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
       setlocationResult(JSON.stringify(location));
       handleCenterChange(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);
       result.lat = location.coords.latitude;
       result.lng = location.coords.longitude;
       resolve(result);
       return;
     } else {
       alert("Location permission denied");
     }
   }
   resolve(result);
});
}
```

**getParkings**

```
async function getParkings(myMapRegion) {
 return new Promise(resolve => {
   console.log("get parking runing")
   console.log("get parkig ", myMapRegion.lat, ", ", myMapRegion.lng);
   await axios.get(`http://${MyIp}:8080/booking/findParking`, {
     params: {
       lat: myMapRegion.lat,
       lng: myMapRegion.lng,
       rad: 10
     },
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
     }
   })
     .then((response) => {
       let parkingSpace = response.data;
       let parking = []
       for (let i = 0; i < parkingSpace.length; i++) {
         parking.push({
           spaceId: parkingSpace[i]._id,
           ownerId: parkingSpace[i].owner,
           location:
             { latitude: parkingSpace[i].latitude, longitude: parkingSpace[i].longitude }
         })
       }
       console.log(parking)
       setSpace(parking);
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err)
     })
     resolve();
  });
 }
```

**getData**

```
async function getData() {
   let myMapRegion = await getAsyncLocation();
   await getParkings(myMapRegion);
}
```